# unsafe:data:image/*;base64,:1 GET unsafe:data:image/*;base64, (Javascript/Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular

I get an image in String64 in json from my Spring Boot App.

html

```
 <img id="userImage" src="{{ userImage }}"/>
```

TypeScript

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {UserService} from "./services/user/user.service";
import {DomSanitizer} from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  private user:any;
  private userImage:any;

  constructor(private userService:UserService, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    //TODO hardcoded...
    this.getUser("admin");
  }

  getUser(username) {
    this.userService.getUser(username).subscribe(user => {
      console.log(user);
      this.user = user;
      this.userImage = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl("data:Image/*;base64," + user.image);
    });
  }
}
```

ERROR:

> core.js:7909 WARNING: sanitizing unsafe URL value SafeValue must use [property]=binding: data:Image/*;base64,/9j/4....

```
unsafe:data:image/*;base64,:1 GET unsafe:data:image/*;base64,
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<img id="userImage" [src]="userImage"/>
```

If you still have problems, please make sure the image you get from the backend is a proper image.